# Salesforce PHP toolkit select query

Tags: php, mysql, salesforce

I am integrating to Salesforce system using their PHP toolkit library.

My problem is that there is a 2000 records limit to each query.

I am looking for a way to split my 4000 records query into 2,

example: records 1 - 2000 and then 2001-4000.

Or if there is another solution I'll be happy to hear.

the query:

```
$query       = "
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,Phone,Email from Contact
";
```

Comment: for first 2000 record `SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,Phone,Email from Contact LIMIT 2000` and for other 2000 record `SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,Phone,Email from Contact LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 2000`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [offset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm) and [limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_limit.htm) keywords in SOQL query, something like

```
$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 0"
```

In your case you should divide size of all records on 2000 (limitation for record counts per query) - you get amount of queries which you should execute for getting all data. Then start to execute the query in loop increasing offset value on 2000 in each next iteration.